# Remove unclosed brackets

Tags: python, regex, string, brackets

How to remove unclosed brackets and its contents if after they have closed block. For example:

```
"(eaardf((eaar)(eaar" -> "eaardf((eaar)"
```

I do so, but I can not make a correct regex:

```
import re
str1 = '(eaardf((eaar)(eaar'
p = re.compile(r'\([a-z)]*.*')
p.sub('', str1)
>>> ''
```

Please help!

Comment: The output you're expecting is not right (if I understand you correctly), "eaardf((eaar)" still have unclosed parenthesis.

Comment: Need "eaardf((eaar)" from "(eaardf((eaar)(eaar".

Comment: Why? What's the logic? The first "(" is not closed. Can you be more specific regarding the rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) (Hint—the answer is no.)

Comment: This can be implemented with "stack" IMO. Will try to solve it with stack.

Comment: MarounMaroun, I can not explain this logic. Just need a result(

Comment: Most modern pattern matching libraries allow for matching nested data directly.

Comment: You can try this pattern: `r'\(([a-zA-Z\(]*\))'`, but it will remove the first '(' every time. I confused that why the first '(' is removed in your example? If you don't want to remove the first '(', you can try this pattern instead: `r'(\([a-zA-Z\(]*\))'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : you cannot with Python regexes.

A very detailed explaination for that has already be given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/3545273) given by DaoWen's comment

Medium answer : the standard `re` module cannot process recursive patterns, but there is a module in Pypi that claims being able to : [regex 2015.03.18](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) : *Recursive and repeated patterns are supported.* - beware untested because when things go too complex for re I prefere to build a dedicated parser eventually through [PLY](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ply) which is a Python implementation of the good old lex+yacc.